# Home receptacles measure from 24 to 96 volts

Tags: wiring

I have a home that is about 14 years old so it is better than the knob-and-tube wiring in my last home.  However, there are no less than three receptacles in the house that couldn't be used as the outlets weren't dependable.  Today I tackled one.  I checked the voltage across the wires and it showed 96v which was odd.  I flipped every breaker and the voltage never changed.  On further inspection, I have 24V between ground and neutral, and 120V between ground and positive.

If someone, upstream, they crossed neutral and ground, that could cause something like this, but why 24V between neutral and ground and 96V between neutral and positive?  Can those voltages give further clues to what might have been done wrong?

Help please!
Lew

Comment: It's not "positive" - it's "hot" and it alters from positive to negative and back  many times each second, since it's AC (Alternating Current) not DC (Direct Current.) The voltages "just happen" to add up to 120V AC - does that ring a bell?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Many digital voltmeters are incredibly sensitive, and will measure large voltages that actually have no "ooomph" behind them. Try plugging in a lamp and then measure the voltage across the lamp.

Comment: Do those outlets work at all? If not, you may be measuring stray voltages (multimeters have a very high impedance which lets them measure stray voltages induced by nearby wires or electrical noise). Plug a simple load (like a lamp or space heater, not a DVD player) into one of the outlets and measure again.

Comment: @Ecnerwal AC voltages do not work that way you are now thinking DC. With 120V there is a hot that is the maximum potential from ground or neutral if there are different values the neutral is said to float. Daniel & Johnny do have a clue ++

Comment: What do you mean by "outlets weren't dependable"? Do you mean they worked sometimes but not always? They worked for small loads but not big ones? Lamps were dimmer than when plugged into another outlet? The answers to these questions will provide more clues as to what is really happening.

Comment: @EdBeal - Your knowledge of how electricity works is poor, at best.  A floating neutral is at a potential between H&G, and the difference is precisely as described in the question. G-N + N-H == G-H.

Comment: Wow, since the ground and neutral are at the same potential in a house I would like so see how that math works.

Comment: @EdBeal - note that he said "floating neutral", which, by definition, is _not_ at the same potential as ground. Otherwise it wouldn't be floating, it'd be bonded.

Comment: Johnny in a 120V household circuit the ground is only there for a fault path. If the neutral is floating the total voltage available on a 120v circuit is from neutral to the hot side this is the maximum potential available to the device there is no addition of the potential to ground. The best example I can give is with a 2 prong device it doesn't mater how high the neutral floats and the device will work fine in most cases as long as the voltage stays above ~110vac.

Comment: @EdBeal While that's true if talking about about the maximum potential of a device plugged into a (properly wired) outlet, the original asker clearly measured potential both between hot & neutral (96V),  neutral & ground (24V),  and hot & ground (120V). No one is saying that a device will work properly on a circuit with a floating neutral even if it has a good ground, but that's not the situation described in the question.

Answer (score 1):

DVM's have a problem.  Unlike traditional voltmeters which use a tiny amount of current from the circuit to move the needle in the meter, DVM's are self-powered and draw essentially no current.

If you lay two wires in parallel and energize one, the floating, unattached wire will "pick up" a voltage by induction (well, capacitance).  This is useless and there's no force behind it (if it wasn't, everyone who lived near high-tension lines would pirate power by laying wires alongside).   You won't see that power on an analog meter, because there's not even enough current to move the gauge needle.

So when you measure a circuit with a DVM, you never know what you're looking at.  It might be real live power or it might be this phantom.

When this happens, put **any** load on the circuit such as a night-light or a 3-lamp circuit tester, and measure again.